# Hibernate 6 OnDelete with CollectionTable causing issue

Tags: hibernate

I'm migrating from spring boot 2.x to 3.x and also hibernate 5.x to 6x and have following field on my entity:

```java
@NotNull
@CollectionTable(
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "e_end_status"),
    name = "ex_active_monitor_end_status",
    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "exFk_monitor_end_trigger")
)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public List<String> getEndStatus() {
    return endStatus;
}
```

when I start application it complains

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unidirectional '@OneToMany' association 'domain.timemonitoring.ActiveTimeMonitoring.endStatus' is annotated '@OnDelete' and must explicitly specify a '@JoinColumn'
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.detectMappedByProblem(CollectionBinder.java:1291)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.bind(CollectionBinder.java:1189)
```

however when I add `@JoinColumn` then it complains with this.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property 'domain.timemonitoring.ActiveTimeMonitoring.endStatus' is a '@ElementCollection' and is directly annotated '@JoinColumn' (specify '@JoinColumn' inside '@JoinTable' or '@CollectionTable')
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.checkAnnotations(CollectionBinder.java:446)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.bindCollection(CollectionBinder.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.bindProperty(PropertyBinder.java:874)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.buildProperty(PropertyBinder.java:788)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.processElementAnnotations(PropertyBinder.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(EntityBinder.java:1026)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.handleIdentifier(EntityBinder.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.bindEntityClass(EntityBinder.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1432)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75)
```

with following code it was working in `hibernate 5.x`

```java
@NotNull
@JoinColumn
@CollectionTable(
    name = "ex_active_monitor_end_status",
    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "exFk_monitor_end_trigger")
)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public List<String> getEndStatus() {
    return endStatus;
}
```

Is there any way how to resolve this? (`hibernate 6.4.1`)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this exception you can simply remove `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)`.
`@ElementCollection` isn't the standalone entity, and Hibernate automatically allpies all operations cascade without explicit indication of `CascadeType`.

Then if you want to make your database FK `ON DELETE CASCADE` while schema DDL command, you can add it to `foreignKeyDefinition`:

```
@CollectionTable(
...
    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "exFk_monitor_end_trigger", foreignKeyDefinition = "foreign key (...) references ... on delete cascade")
)
```

But even in this case Hibernate firstly will try to delete this child element by the separate query.

*I ran into the same problem and didn't find either approval of the previous working feature or 6th version "broken". Maybe it was an undocumented feature.
What is written [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection#:%7E:text=attributes%3E%0A%3C/embeddable%3E-,Basic%20Collections,-%5Bedit%20%7C) suggests that the current behavior is expected for this type of relationship.*